# Return plot from R function

Tags: r, plot

Why won't my R function return or print a plot? The code is below. All of the code seems to work fine, except for the plot. No matter what I do, I can't get R to create the plot when the function is called. Looking around online, I can't find any reason why this wouldn't work.

```
powerc.fun <- function(n,sigma,r){

a <- 0.05
d <- seq(-20,20,2)

power <- rep(NA,length(d))
p.lab <- rep(NA,length(d))

for (j in 1:length(d)){

  mu1 <- 110
  mu2 <- mu1-d[j]  

  reject <- rep(NA,r)

  for (i in 1:r){

    sample1 <- rnorm(n,mu1,sigma)
    sample2 <- rnorm(n,mu2,sigma)

    sample.t <- t.test(sample1,sample2)
    p.val <- sample.t[3]

    reject[i] <- p.val<a 

    power[j] <- sum(reject)/length(reject)
    p.lab[j] <- paste('d=',d[j],sep='')

  }}

d.power <- cbind(d,power)

return(d.power)

p.plot <- plot(d.power[,1], d.power[,2], type="l", xlab=bquote(H[a]), ylab="Power", main="Power Calculations for Two Sample T Test")

print(p.plot)
return(p.plot)

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need `return` if you're calling from the top level (i.e., from the console). If you want to display the plot, just call the `plot` line without storing it, `print`-ing it, or `return`-ing it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799317/custom-function-ggplot-and-return-values

Comment: @Thomas: But I'm not calling from the top level, it is embedded within a function call. If I call the function, it doesn't plot at all. Even without print/return.

Comment: @B.Mr.W.: Can you actual explain what in that link is supposed to help me? The answer to that question says to use "print", which I already explicitly says doesn't work.

Comment: Are you purposefully returning `d.power` prior to reaching the plot?  Or is that simply part of your testing that you forgot to remove when posting your question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works. As suggested, you can save more than one object by using a list:

```
powerc.fun <- function(n,sigma,r){

a <- 0.05
d <- seq(-20,20,2)

power <- rep(NA,length(d))
p.lab <- rep(NA,length(d))

for (j in 1:length(d)){

  mu1 <- 110
  mu2 <- mu1-d[j]  

  reject <- rep(NA,r)

  for (i in 1:r){

    sample1 <- rnorm(n,mu1,sigma)
    sample2 <- rnorm(n,mu2,sigma)

    sample.t <- t.test(sample1,sample2)
    p.val <- sample.t[3]

    reject[i] <- p.val<a 

    power[j] <- sum(reject)/length(reject)
    p.lab[j] <- paste('d=',d[j],sep='')

  }}

d.power <- cbind(d,power)
p.plot <- plot(d.power[,1], d.power[,2], type="l", xlab=bquote(H[a]), ylab="Power", main="Power Calculations for Two Sample T Test")

return(list(p.plot, d.power))

}

# prints the plot and saves d.power values
output <- powerc.fun(100,0.1,10)

# d.power values
output[[2]]
```

But probably you prefer just to save `d.power` and then call it for plotting the graph:

```
powerc.fun <- function(n,sigma,r){

a <- 0.05
d <- seq(-20,20,2)

power <- rep(NA,length(d))
p.lab <- rep(NA,length(d))

for (j in 1:length(d)){

  mu1 <- 110
  mu2 <- mu1-d[j]  

  reject <- rep(NA,r)

  for (i in 1:r){

    sample1 <- rnorm(n,mu1,sigma)
    sample2 <- rnorm(n,mu2,sigma)

    sample.t <- t.test(sample1,sample2)
    p.val <- sample.t[3]

    reject[i] <- p.val<a 

    power[j] <- sum(reject)/length(reject)
    p.lab[j] <- paste('d=',d[j],sep='')

  }}

d.power <- cbind(d,power)

return(d.power)

}

# saves d.power
output <- powerc.fun(100,0.1,10)

# plot
p.plot <- plot(output[,1], output[,2], type="l", xlab=bquote(H[a]), ylab="Power", main="Power Calculations for Two Sample T Test")
```

Answer (score 4):

A call to "return()" ends the function call, so anything after it is ignored

Try getting rid of

```
return (d.power)
```

or moving it to after you define and print the plot.

On a related note, you can't return two objects from one function. Pick one or put them in a list and return the list.

Answer (score 3):

In base `R` you can save plots to disk.  I don't believe you can save them to disk.
Use `ggplot2` instead

```
library(ggplot2)

.
.
.

p.plot <- qplot(as.data.frame(d.power), aes(x=d, y=power)) + 
                 geom_line() + 
                 labs(x=bquote(H[a]), y="Power", title="Power Calculations for Two Sample T Test")
                 # double check the xlab, it might be incorrect 


return(p.plot)
```

Comment: Thanks @MatthewPlourde, I was unfamiliar with that function.  It doesn't seem like you "sort of can" but absolutely can, haha ;)   Post that as an answer?

Comment: The following statement might need an edit: "In base R you can save plots to disk. I don't believe you can save them to disk."

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work on my where variable r is missing, but here is how I call a function and return a plot object.

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)

my.plot <- function() {
 result <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() 
 # you can forget the return below because R will take the last expression which is result as return value
 # return(result)
}

a <- my.plot()
> class(a)
[1] "gg"     "ggplot"
> a
```

[image]