# How to for-loop over a custom function R?

Tags: r, for-loop, probability

I wrote this function which returns the probability that the value 1 does not appear in a random sample when iterated 1000 times for varying sample sizes.

```
bday.function <- function(sample.size){
  x <- vector()
  for (i in 1:1000){
  x[i] <- !any(data.frame(table(sample(1:365, sample.size, replace=TRUE)))$Var1 == 1)
}
  return(mean(x))
}
```

Now I want to use this function and another for-loop to calculate the probability for every sample size between 500 and 1500 and make a simple scatter plot of my results. Here is what I tried:

```
z <- vector()
for (i in 500:1500) {
  z[i] <- bday.function(i)
  return(plot(z))
}
```

Edit: when I run bday.function the output is number of TRUE values divided by the total (1000) TRUE/FALSE outcomes:

```
bday.function(750)
[1] 0.122
```

I would like to replicate this for sample sizes between 500 and 1500 to generate a simple scatter plot

Edit 2: Thanks to everybody for the help! Here's my final solution:

```
x <- vector(length = 1000)

for (i in 1:1000){
  x[i] <- !any(sample(1:365, 500, replace=TRUE) == 1) 
}

x
```

```
bday.function <- function(sample.size){
  x <- vector(length= 1000)
  for (i in 1:1000){
  x[i] <- !any(sample(1:365, sample.size, replace=TRUE) == 1) 
}
  return(mean(x))
}
bday.function(750)
```

```
z <- vector(length = 1000)
tmp.index <- 500:1500
for (i in seq_along(tmp.index)) {
  z[i] <- bday.function(tmp.index[i])
}
#Plot
plot(tmp.index, z, xlab = "sample size", ylab = "Probability of no birthdays")
```

[image]

Comment: We don't have the data to reproduce your code. Could you post them?

Comment: The data is generated by sample(1:365, sample.size, replace=TRUE)

Comment: I started with this code and built up the function from there: data.frame(table(sample(1:365, 500, replace=TRUE)))

Comment: Could you update your original post to show what is the desired outcome both in terms of plot and data structure?

Comment: Done! The function "!any(data.frame(table(sample(1:365, sample.size, replace=TRUE)))$Var1 == 1)" returns a TRUE/FALSE value such that when iterated 1000 times in the for-loop it returns 1000 TRUE/FALSE values. Those values are coerced to integers and mean is calculated.

Comment: Your `bday.function` seems needlessly complex. No reason to use functions like `table, any` and `data.frame` just to check if `1` isn't in a vector. In your case, just check if the `min` is greater than 1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return plot from R function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622028/return-plot-from-r-function)

Comment: I see what you mean, so I should just be able to use this: min(sample(1:365, 500, replace=TRUE)) right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@JohnColeman** pointed in his sage comment, your function can be slow. Try these changes on your code for the printing output. I have run only 60 sims as I need to complete other things:

```
#Function
bday.function <- function(sample.size){
  x <- vector()
  for (i in 1:1000){
    x[i] <- !any(data.frame(table(sample(1:365, sample.size, replace=TRUE)))$Var1 == 1)
  }
  return(mean(x))
}
#Loop
z <- vector()
vec <- 500:1500
for (i in seq_along(vec)) {
  z[i] <- bday.function(vec[i])
}
#Plot
plot(z)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Can you you please explain the use of vec and seq_along? This has appreciably sped up my code but a scan of the documentation hasn't revealed to me why this happens to work. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @myfatson For sure, `seq_along()` creates a sequence from 1 to the length of the object you place inside the function. And `vec` is just a vector maybe the key here is the use of `:` that can help you to also create a sequence like `1:5` will create `1,2,3,4,5`. Hope that is clear for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```r
bday.function <- function(sample.size) {
  
  mean(sapply(seq(1000), function(x)
    +!any(sample(365, sample.size, replace = TRUE) == 1)))
}

x <- 500:1500
y <- sapply(x, bday.function)
plot(x, y, xlab = "sample size", ylab = "Probability of no birthdays")
```

[image]

Comment: This is definitely what I was looking for! Unfortunately I was doing this for an assignment that specified for-loops in base R. Despite knowing that this would be much easier with sapply, I'm trying to practice my base R to round out my knowledge.